# Why do I can not get a corrected result of knn test in R?

Tags: r, knn, stat

After i enter all the code of the knn procedure and show the result as a table, the becomes

```
         data_test_target
data_pred    a    b
        a 2289  131
        b    0    0
```

sth like this.
why cant i get any prediction of b in here? Do i make any mistake? Thank you.
Code as below

```
data1<-data[,-1]
data_train <- data1[1:1200,]
data_test <- data1[1201:1542,]
data_train_target <-data[1:1200,1]
data_test_target <-data[1201:1542,1]
data_pred <- knn(data_train,data_test,cl=data_train_target,k=40)
table( data_pred,data_test_target)
```

Comment: Hi! are you sure that in the `train` data you have some observations of class `b`? check with `table(data_train[, 1])`

Comment: Also, it would help if you show us a reproducible example, what's `train` and `test`data like?

Comment: Hi Rlave,
oh yes im sure there are some observation of class b in the train data. However, I do the `data1<-data[,-1]` to not adding the class as a variable. Does it correct?

Comment: the train and test data is from a same group of data. The data is full of binary factor variable  Therefore, i do the `as.numeric` code to all variable from the data in order to use knn in R(only numeric data can be used).

Comment: yes, you remove the first column in `data` keeping the rest, It's correct as long as the class is the first column

Comment: you could even do `data_train <- data1[1:1200, -1]`, and avoid the use of `data1`

Comment: if we can't replicate your example, it can be hard to find the problem, it looks ok to me based on what you showed.

Comment: you mean `data_train <- data[1:1200, -1]` ?

Comment: yes, the same for `data_test`

Comment: i have just try it and the result remains the same. Thanks anyway I will try to figure it out :)

Comment: I didn't say that it was the solution, it was just a suggestion. Again, we need to see the data to understand what's happening. At least add the output from `str(data)`

Comment: ah also try with a lower value for `k`